# string not optimized enough for string literals

Tags: c++, string, stl

In a C++ project of mine I'm one step before replacing all `char*` with `std::string` but I find one certain occasion where `std::string` fails miserably.

Imagine I have these 2 functions:

```
void foo1(const std::string& s)
{
    ...
}

void foo2(const char* s)
{
    ...
}
```

If I write something like this:

```
const char* SL = "Hello to all!";

foo1(SL); // calls malloc, memcpy, free
foo2(SL);
```

in `foo1` the `SL` will implicitly converted into `std::string`. This means that the `std::string` constructor will allocate memory and it will copy the string literal to that buffer. In `foo2` though nothing of all these will happen.

In most implementations `std::string` is supposed to be super optimized (Copy On Write for instance) but when I construct it with a `const char*` it is not. And my question is this: Why this happens? Am I missing something? Is my standard library not optimized enough or for some reason (that I'm not aware of) this is totally unsafe?

Comment: Copy on write isn't really a "super optimization". I believe GCC's standard library still uses it, but only because it made sense 10 years ago, before multithreading was the norm. A sane library implementation made today would avoid COW like the plague.

Comment: I think the standard doesn't even allow COW because of the iterator invalidation requirements of the member functions.

Comment: Afaik C++03 allowed COW. I believe C++11 forbids it

Answer (score 21):

Actually, your worries would go away(*) if you changed the literal:

```
std::string const SL = "Hello to all!";
```

I added the `const` for you.

Now, calling `foo1` will not involve any copying (at all), and calling `foo2` can be achieved at little cost:

```
foo1(SL);         // by const-reference, exact same cost than a pointer
foo2(SL.c_str()); // simple pointer
```

If you want to move to `std::string`, don't only switch the functions interfaces, switch the variables (and constants) too.

(*) The original answer assumed that `SL` was a global constant, if it is a variable local to a function, then it could be made `static` if one truly wishes to avoid building it at each call.

Comment: One additional point: if the string literal is in a function, you might want to make it static.

Comment: Doesn't that mean all of your string literals will get copied to the heap at startup?

Comment: Why would worries go away? Now, std::string object will be constructed/destructed on enter/exit scope, which might lead to the same memory alloc/dealloc as previously (depending on std::string implementation). Making it const doesn't make it static, does it?

Comment: @7vies: exact, I had assumed that `SL` was a global constant originally. James already pointed out that if it is in a function, it should be static as well.

Comment: @Matthieu: interesting, for some weird reason my mind had filtered out comment from James :) You could mention "static" in your answer, though, to avoid people wondering why would worries go away

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that there is no way for the std::string class to recognize whether the `const char*` pointer is a global character literal or not:

```
const char *a = "Hello World";
const char *b = new char[20];
```

The char* pointer might get invalid at any time (for example when it's a local variable and the function/scope ends), thus `std::string` must become an exclusive owner of the string. This can only be achieved by copying.

The following example demonstrates why it is necessary:

```
std::string getHelloWorld()  {
  char *hello = new char[64];
  strcpy(hello, "Hello World");
  std::string result = (const char *)hello;  // If std::string didn't make a copy, the result could be a garbage
  delete[] hello;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Actually, a string literal is a `char[N]` where N is the lenght + 1 (null terminator).

Comment: Why the `new` ? Allocating the buffer on the stack would work as well: `char const hello[] = "Hello World";`

Comment: @MatthieuM.: And your version would be exception safe, while dark_charlie's is not as the string-constructor is not no-throw.

Comment: The new and delete is more eye catching, I think it better demonstrates that something is wrong. Allocating the buffer on the stack would be undefined behavior as well but in practice it would actually most probably work because of the way string literals are allocated by the compiler.

Comment: That was what I was missing and the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

`std::string` isn't a silver bullet. It's intended to be the best possible implementation of a general-purpose mutable string which owns its memory, and which is reasonably cheap to use with C APIs. Those are common scenarios, but they don't match **every** instance of string usage.

String literals, as you mention, do not fit this use case well. They use statically allocated memory, so `std::string` can't and shouldn't try to take ownership of the memory. And these strings are *always* read-only, so `std::string` can't allow you to modify them.

`std::string` creates a copy of the string data passed to it, and then works on this copy internally.

If you want to operate on constant strings whose lifetime is handled elsewhere (in the case of string literals, it's handled by the runtime library which initializes and frees static data), then you might want to use a different string representation. Perhaps just a simple `const char*`.

Comment: *It's the best possible implementation of a mutable string which owns its memory.* Nope. Not even close. The stringent requirement placed by `.c_str()` costs. A best possible implementation would probably use B-Trees to avoid all those costly reallocations when the string is big and gets modified.

Comment: but then it'd lose contiguity, which would make conversion to C strings more costly. There are a lot of tradeoffs to be considered. :) But I clarified my answer a bit.

Comment: Yes, this is why I mentionned `c_str`. I believe that the SGI STL had a `rope` class to cover the case when C interaction is not required.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Indeed there's a `std::rope` in SGI's. However, `string` and `rope` have different use cases: The first is better for some use-cases (fast iterators, quick append), the latter for some others (think of text editors for an application, but would lose on iterating). _Best_ for this matter is highly subjective.

Comment: @Matthie M.: Yes, `rope` is a heavy-duty `string`. Get it? ;-)

Comment: @phresnel: indeed, there is no silver bullet. It reminds me of a discussion in python: `list` vs `blist` (which uses Indexed B-Trees). Most lists are dead simple and suffer from the overhead (no matter how small) of the more complex representation.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That reminds me of Scott Meyer's recommendation to think about whether a sorted vector might be better in your case than full blown maps/sets, w.r.t. performance/overhead.

Comment: @phresnel: Loki's [AssocVector](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00025.html)! I personally tend to use vectors/arrays for static stuff.